# Php Regex to insert character after first all-capital letter word in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I'm trying to use a preg_replace or similar php function to:
- identify the first all capital letter word in a string,
- and insert a character directly after it (a dash or semi-colon will do)
- the all capital letter word should be 3 characters long or more.

So far I have the regular expression:

```
/(?<!\ )([^A-Z{3,}])/
```

But, this isn't working in terms of only words that are 3+ characters. I'm also not sure I have it 'strictly' only looking at the very first word.

I believe that once I have the regex sorted out - this

```
$string = "LONDON On November 12th twelve people...";
$replaced_string = preg_replace('/myregex/',': ', $string);
```

will output as the following

```
LONDON: On November 12th twelve people..."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a fairly simple regex, really:

```
$replacedString = preg_replace('/\b([A-Z]{3,})\b/', '$1: ', $string);
```

It works like this:

- `\b`: word boundary. This detects the start and end of a *"word"*
- `([A-Z]{3,})`: Match 3 or more upper-case characters. The brackets capture this part of the match, so we can use it in the replacement string
- `\b`: Another word boundary

Replace this match with:

- `'$1: '`: the `$1` refers back to the first captured group (the 3 or more upper case characters). To this, we're adding a colon and a space. That will be our replacement string

This will add the colon and space after ***all*** upper-case words of 3 or more characters. To replace only 1 word, just pass a limit to `preg_replace`:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/\b([A-Z]{3,})\b/', '$1: ', $string, 1);
```

Where that last argument is the number of matches you wish to replace. -1 for all, 1 for 1, 2 for 2, etc...

## [Demo](https://eval.in/484896)

Judging by your sample string, the upper-case words are city names. It's possible for city names to contain a dash, or even a space. To address this, you might want to match all strings containing upper-case chars, dashes and spaces:

```
$replaceAll = preg_replace('/\b([A-Z -]{2,}[A-Z])\b/', '$1: ', $string);
```

## [Demo 2](https://eval.in/484898)

What changed:

- `([A-Z -]{2,}`: The capturing match start with upper-case chars (2 or more, not 3), but also matches spaces and dashes.
- `[A-Z])`: The last character of the captured group *must* be an upper-case character, this avoids capturing the trailing spaces or dashes. The result is that we capture stuff like *"NEW YORK"* or *"FOO-TOWN"*, but not *"ON - Something"*.

The rest is the same as before. If you want to allow for other characters that might occur (like a dot) just add them to the first part of the capturing group. The most complete pattern will probably be something like this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/\b([A-Z][A-Z .-]+[A-Z])\b/', '$1: ', $string);
```

This ensures the captured group starts, and ends with an upper case character, and contains any number of upper-case chars, spaces, dots and dashes in between. So this will match something like *"ST. LEWIS"*, too

Comment: @stribizhev: Yes, updated my answer to include a note about the limit argument you can pass to `preg_replace`

Comment: This is genius - and a VERY helpful answer. Thanks for the excellent explanations. I'd be interested to know if there's a way to strictly do this to the first word/chars only of a string, but even without, this does the job I need it to.